# Uneditable Transformed Row Source for MS Access Chart Keeps Resetting Sort Order

Tags: charts, microsoft-access

Inserting a bar chart object into a Microsoft Access form brings the data into view with a sort order I did not preset when I first designed the underlying query.

[image]

I can see that the unwanted sort order pops up in a fixed, uneditable `Transformed Row Source` property that overrides the `Row Source` property.

```
`Row Source`: SELECT * FROM SumOfUtilizationByPersonnelAndDate WHERE [Month] >= 7 AND [Month] <= 7 AND [Year] >= 2019 AND [Year] <= 2019 ORDER BY [SumOfUtilization] DESC , [Created By] DESC; 

`Transformed Row Source`: SELECT [Created By], Sum([SumOfUtilization]) AS [SumOfSumOfUtilization] FROM (SELECT * FROM SumOfUtilizationByPersonnelAndDate WHERE [Month] >= 7 AND [Month] <= 7 AND [Year] >= 2019 AND [Year] <= 2019 ORDER BY [SumOfUtilization] DESC , [Created By] DESC) GROUP BY [Created By] ORDER BY [Created By]
```

As soon as I select my prepared, properly sorted query in the `Row Source` property, that immediately causes the `Transformed Row Source` property to get written--and the ORDER BY clause in it seems to have a mind of its own, choosing columns and sort sequencing that I didn't want.

Also, the `Transformed Row Source` property is totally uneditable! Attempting to manually edit the `Transformed Row Source` property's SQL back the way I want causes the error message,

> "**You can't assign a value to this object.**
>
> The object may be a control on a read-only form.
>
> The object may be on a form that is open in Design view.
>
> The value may be too large for this field."

What can I do to get this bar chart to sort the data how I want? The query does display the data in the right order in View mode. Why can't the bar chart just do the same?

I've tried Bar Clustered, Bar Stacked, and Bar Stacked 100% chart type and all end up with the same issue. Note that I do need this to remain a bar chart.

**UPDATE**: No comments made below up to Sept. 17th, 2019, have helped, other than update me with the understanding that Microsoft Access has recently introduced Modern Charts which differ from Classic Charts. What I am using is a Modern Chart. The comments up to Sept 17th have only had me try to recreate this as a Classic Chart with no better outcomes, but rather more disadvantages.

**UPDATE 2** (9/21/2019): Now I tried removing my ORDER BY clause in my Row Source query but the sorting still gets set wrong. However, I learned through that exercise that the *Axis (Category)* Data Source property under Chart Settings is what defines/selects that ORDER BY field list--which marries both sort order and category data selection in the chart--a very unfortunate marriage indeed because I do NOT want that! Whatever fields I check for Axis Category, they will appear in the Transformed Row Source ORDER BY clause AND ALSO be cast as part of my category axis! Not good! I want the Created By field ONLY to be the *Axis (Category)*, and the sort order (ORDER BY) clause to be set to something completely separate, which is SumOfUtilization! This seems to be a Microsoft bug that I am not sure a workaround exists for yet! I've submitted Feedback to Microsoft via the Microsoft Access menu for now.

[image]

Comment: The [Transformed Row Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.chart.transformedrowsource) property is readonly, but generated from a combination of the RowSource property and selected axis fields.

Comment: Right, I get that. But is there a way to set its ORDER BY clause how I want it?

Comment: Change axix fields? I don't know. Add query, axix fields, chart type, etc ... Maybe someone knows. What about using Excel?

Comment: Maybe [Changing the order of items](https://www.ellenfinkelstein.com/pptblog/changing-the-order-of-items-in-a-chart/) helps.

Comment: That might be fine for Excel but this is Microsoft Access I'm talking about, and switching to Excel is a last resort.

Comment: Should apply to access too. I just tested and I can select`Categories in Reverse Order `as described.

Comment: I don't know what version of Access you are using. I have Office 365 and there is no such Format Axis menu. I cannot select any axis individually to change its unique settings. There's no Axis Options menu. I cannot select any element inside the chart, much less edit it outside the finite options available to me in the Property Sheet.

Comment: Me Office 2007. In design-view, I can`Chart-Object`->Edit (right-click on chart-object.). In chart-obejct design-view, I can select the Axis (click on) and get a context-menu-> Format Axis.

Comment: Office 365's version of MS Access differs from Access 2017 in that it has no PivotCharts, and it seems that there are new chart types now and that this is what I'm seeing---I suppose what you are speaking of requires the use of classic charts. I need to learn where I harness that...

Comment: Just tested on Access 2013, still works.

Comment: BTW, I did go back and see that there is another way to create a chart in Access version 1902 that comes with Office 365 ProPlus, by using the Design toolbar ribbon. It's found in the list of available object types that can be inserted into a form. However, this method seems archaic and dependent on older code I suppose. Not only does Format Axis not lead to any method of sorting my data, but the visualization is also very jittery and unstable. What's more, it seems to not have a dynamic link to my data that could be refreshed later.

Comment: I suggest to roll up the relevant comments into the post and clean them out. It's too tiring to go through all this stuff in order to understand what you already tried so we don't duplicate your efforts. Especially as you need the answer fast. Show also an example of the data and of the sort order you are seeing.

Comment: Done. I chose not to delete my own comments above because it would make others' comments harder to follow. System won't let me delete theirs. I still need help.

Comment: Please delete the useless comments. Why is the transformed query using aggregation? The following might not apply to newer versions of Access: The query in design view might have a big sigma button that can be clicked to unaggregate. Or the field selected needs to change the aggregation to "None". Or the chart needs setting to 'By Column'.

Comment: Site won't let me delete other people's comments. To answer your questions, SumOfUtilizationByPersonnelAndDate is necessarily an aggregated query, and non-negotiable. Please explain what you mean by setting the chart to "By Column".

Comment: You can always delete your own comments. If "By Column" is meaningless to you then it doesn't apply to your version.

Comment: BTW, I've been watching codekabinett at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LW2Ct8Npyzs and learning about many limitations of Modern Charts, and the Transformed Row Source property is discussed there as being directly uneditable, as I've personally learned--but some elements can be indirectly edited via the Chart Settings pane. What I didn't hear there is whether the transformed sort column can be somehow manually chosen--and that's what could solve my dilemma right away if it were possible! I'm becoming less confident that this level of customization will be possible with this Access version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW, because time had run out without a satisfactory solution in Access, what I ended up doing was creating an Excel spreadsheet that linked up to my Access query using Excel's Get Data button, generating a PivotTable out of that inside Excel, and creating a chart based off that PivotTable. Excel's charting capabilities are far more excellent and capable than what seems currently available in Access, and I got my sort order to come up just like I wanted. Not the solution I was hoping for since now I am forcing my client to use two separate Office products, but it works.

PS: Thanks to everyone who tried to help. I lost 50 points in reputation that I would have gladly given to someone as a bounty if they could help me but the time ran out per superuser.com. Nothing I could do to assign those points to anyone now and I don't get them back either.

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting/ordering by individual **"SumOfUtilization"**, but presenting/selecting **"Sum([SumOfUtilization])"**.

Why don't you just add a GROUP BY clause (to the [Created By] field) in your original query and aggregate by "Sum([SumOfUtilization])" so the ORDER BY matches the Axis?

```
SELECT [Created By], Sum([SumOfUtilization]) AS [SumOfSumOfUtilization] FROM SumOfUtilizationByPersonnelAndDate WHERE [Month] >= 7 AND [Month] <= 7 AND [Year] >= 2019 AND [Year] <= 2019 GROUP BY [Created By] ORDER BY Sum([SumOfUtilization]) DESC , [Created By] DESC;
```

You can ORDER BY an aggregate value by re-stating an aggregate for that field ("ORDER BY Sum([SumOfUtilization])"), or by referring to it by its Select Ordinal in the ORDER BY clause ("ORDER BY 2").

Or you could query your original query as a sub-query doing the same GROUP BY aggregation shown above.

If necessary, there are several ways you can swap the Axis display once you get the data organized correctly. Specifically, you could adjust the Charts display settings, swap the Major/Minor Axis, or manipulate the order of SELECT from the query.

#### DETAILS

As I recall, an embedded ORDER BY clause OVERRIDES all object level sorting. Once the ORDER BY is out of SQL, the presentation objects are able to apply their own sort ordering.

To override this use the original query as a Data Source for a sub-query which you use as your real Data Source. This is what the chart object is doing to you here.

Chart API Reference: "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.chart.transformedrowsource"

> This [Transformed Row Source] string is generated from a *combination* of the **RowSource property** and **selected axis fields**.

Looking at your Row Source SELECT it looks like the order you are selecting in is what the chart is defaulting to as the AxisOrder. *You can explicitly select your values to sequence the Chart manually the way you want.*

As in, SELECT **[SumOfUtilization], [Created By]** ...

```
`Row Source`: SELECT [SumOfUtilization], [Created By], * FROM SumOfUtilizationByPersonnelAndDate WHERE [Month] >= 7 AND [Month] <= 7 AND [Year] >= 2019 AND [Year] <= 2019 ORDER BY [SumOfUtilization] DESC , [Created By] DESC;
```

Edit: clean up.

Comment: Well, the ORDER BY clause in my Row Source property is exactly how I want it. I want SumOfUtilization to be the first column to sort by, followed by the Created By column. The trouble is that the Transformed Row Source property gets set by MS Access and I can't touch it, and it gets somehow hard-coded to sort by the Created By column--overriding what's in Row Source. This is happening at the chart object level, and my intended sort order as spelled in Row Source gets overridden. Now I tried removing my ORDER BY clause in my Row Source query but the sorting still gets set wrong.

Comment: It's the Modern Bar Chart new in recent version s of Access. Mine is v1902, coming with Office 365.

Comment: If I change the order of the field list (SELECT clause) in the query, the new field sequence does appear in the Chart Settings | Axis (Category) pane, but I am still at square one because the moment I check Utilization first, Access throws it in as the category text. I need the Created By field to be charted as category, but the Utilization values to be used for the sort. Clicking the Utilization checkbox only causes the category axes to *display* Utilization data instead of my intended Created By field, throwing everything off once again.

Comment: Are you trying to get the chart shown in your picture to be sorted top-to-bottom by the total utilization (not the "created by" person name) ? Name (Created By) labels down the left side, sorted by their total utilization, and utilization percent across the bottom?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the chart shown in my picture to be sorted top-to-bottom by the SumOfUtilization (not the "Created By" person name).

Comment: Did the GROUP BY work? Is summing multiple utilization's by each person not what you want either?

Comment: Did [ShieldOfSalvation](https://superuser.com/users/715264/shieldofsalvation) just take the answer, let the bounty expire, and abandon the question?

Comment: None of the above ever worked.

Comment: Did you add the GROUP BY clause to your original query, and aggregate (by "Sum([SumOfUtilization])" ) or ORDER BY (the "Max([SumOfUtilization])" )?

Answer (score 0):

I found on my chart properties, when I selected my axis there were properties I could change (Watch for little down arrows to appear to the right of the options you select. Its easy to miss) and then when I went back to that transform thing (that I gad spent hours getting frustrated with) I could see it had now updated itself to do what I wanted all along. It was still transforming, but now doing it in a way that mimicked what my underlying query was doing so no difference in the end.